# Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of One Punch Man anime end in?

Tags: one-punch-man

If you want to keep following One Punch Man story in the manga, after second season of the anime ended, you need to know which chapter of the manga the anime ends.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of One Punch Man anime end in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated here, [Episode 24](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_24) of the 2nd season of *One Punch Man* is based on **Chapters 83-84** (Volume 16) of the manga. If you want to pick up where the anime ended, either you start reading on these chapters or proceed to the one that follows, which is **Chapter 85**.